# Tipsi-stripe localization on react-native

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I'm tinkering with tipsi-stripe's paymentRequestWithCardForm() method to make it support UI localization (project app is supposed to support EN, IT and DE). I'm browsing tipsi-stripe's [image: documentation] and can't find anything localization-related.
Also changing language settings of the device changes UI only partly (see screenshots).

[image: EN]

[image: It]

[image: De]

Comment: I'm curious how to do this too. Since Stripe recently release their [official React Native SDK](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native), I'd look into that and consider tipsi-stripe dead.